# C#/WPF - Adding a CornerRadius to a ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, cornerradius

I want create a ToggleButton with round corners by using my CornerRadius property. As you can see in the code below, i already added a cornerRadius property to my xaml ToggleButton to pass a radius value. But i can't find a way to use this value in c# to create a ToggleButton with round corners.

C#

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(int), typeof(MyToggleButton), 
    new PropertyMetadata(0)); //Default CornerRadius = 0

public int CornerRadius
{
   get { return (int)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
   set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
}
```

XAML

```
<custom:MyToggleButton Height="25" Content="Test" CornerRadius="15" />
```

So how can i create a toggleButton with round corners by using my property "CornerRadius"?
Would be great if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't create a new control just in order to make it round - that's what templates are for and that's what makes WPF so great! You could simply define a new template for the `ToggleButton`.

If you insist on inheriting your own control, you'll need to define for it a new default style that will also include a control template that will have a border that uses your `CornerRadius` property. You can base your new template on [the default control template for `ToggleButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468212.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction, But i'm fairly new to WPF. I should bind my CornerRadius property to the border of my copy of the default control template for ToggleButton. This maybe a stupid question but i can't find a way to link to c# class myToggleButton to a template.

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx) is a good place to start in order to understand how to extend/customize controls in WPF.